# Heroku FlyingSphinx Configuration needed for ThinkingSphinx::Configuration.instance.controller.running?

Tags: thinking-sphinx

We ported our Rails 5.2 app to Heroku and were able to get *almost* everything working with FlyingSphinx.

Search and indexing work well but as a convenience to our users, we try to let them know when the daemon is down for service or if we're re-indexing.

Previously, we were able to use

`ThinkingSphinx::Configuration.instance.controller.running?`

But this always returns `false` on Heroku even if the daemon is running.

Our `thinking_sphinx.yml` doesn't specify file locations or information on where the pid is, so I suspect this may be the issue; however, I can't find anywhere that would explain what to use in `thinking_sphinx.yml` for Heroku/FlyingSphinx, if it's at all necessary https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v3/advanced_config.html.

Our `thinking_sphinx.yml` looks like this now:

```
common: &common
  mem_limit: 40M
  64bit_timestamps: true

development:
  <<: *common
test:
  <<: *common
  mysql41: 9307
  quiet_deltas: true
staging:
  <<: *common
  quiet_deltas: true
production:
  <<: *common
  version: '2.2.11'
  quiet_deltas: true
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I've not had this requested before, but it's definitely possible:

```
require "flying_sphinx/commands" if ENV["FLYING_SPHINX_IDENTIFIER"]

ThinkingSphinx::Commander.call(
  :running,
  ThinkingSphinx::Configuration.instance,
  {}
)
```

When this is called locally, it'll check the daemon via the pid file, but when it's called on a Heroku app using Flying Sphinx, it talks to the Flying Sphinx API to get the running state. Hence, it's important to only run the `require` call for Heroku-hosted environments - there's no point having local/test envs calling the Flying Sphinx API.

Setting file/pid locations in Heroku/Flying Sphinx environments are mostly not going to do anything, because Flying Sphinx overwrites these anyway to match the standardised approach on their servers. The exceptions are for stopfiles/exceptions/etc, and those corresponding files are uploaded to Flying Sphinx so the daemon there can be configured appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented that and deployed it to a review app. The approach you suggested still returns `false` yet the service is started. I also tried the statement from a Rails console and got the same result, just to cross my t's and dot my i's.

Comment: Hmm… I tested it on one of my apps and got true.  Which versions of the thinking-sphinx and flying-sphinx gems are you using?

Comment: flying-sphinx 2.2.0  & thinking-sphinx 4.4.1

Comment: @BobbyWallace I think I figured out why it wasn't working, and have edited the answer - note the conditional require statement just for Heroku-hosted environments.